# MySQL connection 'asking for reconnection'

Tags: php, mysql

To explain, I'll divide the code into subparts: (same scope)

```
<?php
### part 1
connect_db(); // My db connection function - works fine

### part 2
/* lot of code without closing mysql connection - these lines works fine too */

### part 3
/* lot of statements like the following */
if( $statement ){
    /* some code */
    mysql_close();
    exit;
}

### part 4
/* and after 2400 lines */
$query = mysql_query("SELECT row FROM table_name WHERE row = 'some_condition'");
while ( $fetch = mysql_fetch_object( $query ) ) {
    $myObj = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT row FROM table_name WHERE row = 'some_condition'"));
}
?>
```

At part 1, 2 and 3, any try to connect to db will result successfully. It's very important to mention that **every `mysql_close()` is immediately suceded by an `exit`**.

At part 4, a try to connect to db will give the following result - **[EDIT]** in the `mysql_query` inside of the `while`:

```
mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)...
```

It's not an isolated case, once I've experiencing this issue for a long time in many files with apparently no error in my code.

My **PHP version** is **5.2.3** and **Apache 2.2.4(Win32)**

Anyone know what is causing this 'disconnection' after a few lines of code without an explicity order to close connection?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding

You can use the mysql_ping() function to test the status of the connection and reconnect when it returns false.

Based on that you can handle it in PHP Code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know and I am currently circumventing this problem by calling the connection function, but the point is what is causing this? or: It's normal?